# How to read a cookie set by the Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie with a value that I get from the server to be used in subsequent calls. I have an Lwc component where I am trying to do it.

below is the code that I am using  to create a cookie

```
createCookie(name, value, days) {
      var expires;
      if (days) {
          const date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
          expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
      }
      else {
          expires = "";
      }
      document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
  }
```

The cookie is set properly in the browser. To Read the cookie from the browser I am using the below code

```
getCookie(name) {
  var value = 'LSKey[' + c +']' + name; // namespace 
  return value;
  }
```

I am getting an error: c is not defined  while loading the component

Note: I don't have a namespace in the org.

I really appreciate it if someone can please let me know how to read a cookie value in js from the Browser.

Thank You

Comment: Does it need to be a cookie, or are you open to using localStorage, which is far, far easier to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the namespace; the cookie property takes care of this for you.

I [wrote an app](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/HUFgNnAeHc6uHNXd0GdM/src/app.js) that demonstrates this for you.

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  save() {
    const key = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="key"]').value;
    const value = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="value"]').value;
    this.createCookie(key, value, 1);
  }
  load() {
    const name = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="key"]').value;
    const valueEl = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="value"]');
    valueEl.value = this.loadCookie(name);

  }
  createCookie(name, value, days) {
      var expires;
      if (days) {
          const date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
          expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
      }
      else {
          expires = "";
      }
      document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
  }
  loadCookie(name) {
    return document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith(`${name}=`))?.split('=')[1];
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-input label="Key" data-id="key"></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Value" data-id="value"></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button-group>
        <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={save}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="Load" onclick={load}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-button-group>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, I am getting an error 'Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'split')                                                                                                        getCookie(name) {
  return document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith(`${name}=`)).split('=')[1];
  }

Comment: @Donald Let me try it in Salesforce. It'll take a few minutes.

Comment: @Donald It works in my org. Keep in mind that this doesn't include any error handling; the cookie must be saved before it can be loaded. I added a null-safe operator in this code to prevent that error.

Comment: Thanks for your help !!. It's Perfect